# Jersey, restful web service, cross domain access deny

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I use netbeans to create restful web service and got the error of "cross domain access deny"

I have add the "cross origin resource filter"

following is my code.

```
@Provider
public class CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext response) {
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
}

}
```

and

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}

private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(WebService.CategoryFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(WebService.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter.class);
    resources.add(WebService.ProductFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(WebService.ReviewFacadeREST.class);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is, that only the `Content-Type` header is allowed in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. Please look for a header `Access-Control-Request-Headers` in the request... set the content in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header or try this code:

```
String reqHead = requestContext.getHeaderString("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
if (null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals("")) {
    responseHeaders.putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
}
```

In general: for security reasons you should not use wildcards and code like this in the production environment.